# Integrity constraint violation for Symfony User

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I'm getting this following error

> [Application] Jan  5 00:03:10 |CRITICA| CONSOL Error thrown while running command "make:migration". Message: "An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Champ: 'TABLE_NAME' dans where clause est ambigu

When running the migration command after creating the user entity

```
created: src/Entity/User.php
created: src/Repository/UserRepository.php
updated: src/Entity/User.php
updated: config/packages/security.yaml
```

Success!

Next Steps:

- Review your new App\Entity\User class.
- Use make:entity to add more fields to your User entity and then run make:migration.
- Create a way to authenticate! See https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
  PS C:\Users\chris\Desktop\projets\Matehub-Api> php bin/console make:migration

> In ExceptionConverter.php line 72:
> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Champ: 'TABLE_NAME' dans where clause est ambigu
> `

I don't really get what is happening considering that I just used the symfony command to generate the User class.

Ive been able to create the database without any issue using

> php bin/console doctrine:database:create

THis is what I have in dev.log file

> [2024-01-05T00:03:10.055039+00:00] doctrine.DEBUG: Executing statement: SELECT c.TABLE_NAME,       c.COLUMN_NAME        AS field,            IF(         c.COLUMN_TYPE = 'longtext'         AND EXISTS(             SELECT * from information_schema.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS              WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'matehub'             AND TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME             AND CHECK_CLAUSE = CONCAT(                 'json_valid(`',                     c.COLUMN_NAME,                 '`)'             )         ),         'json',         c.COLUMN_TYPE     )       AS type,        c.IS_NULLABLE        AS `null`,        c.COLUMN_KEY         AS `key`,        c.COLUMN_DEFAULT     AS `default`,        c.EXTRA,        c.COLUMN_COMMENT     AS comment,        c.CHARACTER_SET_NAME AS characterset,        c.COLLATION_NAME     AS collation FROM information_schema.COLUMNS c     INNER JOIN information_schema.TABLES t         ON t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME      WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION (parameters: array{"1":"matehub","2":"matehub"}, types: array{"1":2,"2":2}) {"sql":"SELECT c.TABLE_NAME,       c.COLUMN_NAME        AS field,\n           IF(\n        c.COLUMN_TYPE = 'longtext'\n        AND EXISTS(\n            SELECT * from information_schema.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS \n            WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'matehub'\n            AND TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME\n            AND CHECK_CLAUSE = CONCAT(\n                'json_valid(`',\n                    c.COLUMN_NAME,\n                '`)'\n            )\n        ),\n        'json',\n        c.COLUMN_TYPE\n    )       AS type,\n       c.IS_NULLABLE        AS `null`,\n       c.COLUMN_KEY         AS `key`,\n       c.COLUMN_DEFAULT     AS `default`,\n       c.EXTRA,\n       c.COLUMN_COMMENT     AS comment,\n       c.CHARACTER_SET_NAME AS characterset,\n       c.COLLATION_NAME     AS collation\nFROM information_schema.COLUMNS c\n    INNER JOIN information_schema.TABLES t\n        ON t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME\n     WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION","params":{"1":"matehub","2":"matehub"},"types":{"1":2,"2":2}} []

> [2024-01-05T00:03:10.059570+00:00] console.CRITICAL: Error thrown while running command "make:migration". Message: "An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Champ: 'TABLE_NAME' dans where clause est ambigu" {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\NonUniqueFieldNameException(code: 1052): An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Champ: 'TABLE_NAME' dans where clause est ambigu at C:\Users\chris\Desktop\projets\MateHub-Api\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Driver\API\MySQL\ExceptionConverter.php:72)\n[previous exception] [object] (Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception(code: 1052): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Champ: 'TABLE_NAME' dans where clause est ambigu at C:\Users\chris\Desktop\projets\MateHub-Api\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Driver\PDO\Exception.php:28)\n[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Champ: 'TABLE_NAME' dans where clause est ambigu at C:\Users\chris\Desktop\projets\MateHub-Api\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Driver\PDO\Statement.php:130)","command":"make:migration","message":"An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Champ: 'TABLE_NAME' dans where clause est ambigu"} []

EDIT : Actually I think this might not be related to the User entity but to the installation itself as the error seems to remain even if I remove the User entity and repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `.env` file for your DATABASE_URL and make sure the "serverVersion" is correct.

For instance, if connecting to MySQL 8, make sure it doesn't say "serverVersion=10.11.2-MariaDB", etc

Comment: but in that case, the CLI creating the database would have failed too no ? In my case it didn't failed. I have  DATABASE_URL="mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname?serverVersion=10.11.2-MariaDB&charset=utf8mb4" that being said select version() in my db return me 8.2.0.

Comment: Just tested to change and only put the 8.2.0...and it sounds to work now. I get why it wasn't working...but i don't get how the database creation managed to work. Anyway, great save there thanks, cause honestly I didn't saw any other topic with that error. It's kinda tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.
Symfony project *test* created
Database *test* created
Entity *Test* with a field *test* created
symfony console make:migration

error(s)

```
otros % symfony console make:migration                              
    [critical] Error thrown while running command "make:migration". Message: "An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'TABLE_NAME' in where clause is ambiguous"
    
In ExceptionConverter.php line 72:                                                                                                      
    An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'TABLE_NAME' in where clause is ambiguous  
    
In Exception.php line 28:
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'TABLE_NAME' in where clause is ambiguous  
                                                                                                              
In Statement.php line 130:
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'TABLE_NAME' in where clause is ambiguous  
                                                                                                           
make:migration
```

composer.json => requirements section

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=8.1",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.11",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.17",
    "symfony/console": "6.4.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "6.4.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^2",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.4.*",
    "symfony/runtime": "6.4.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "6.4.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.52"
},
```

Can anyone see the light at the end of the tunnel?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just as Chris explained, I also had another DB version. I corrected mine and everything works.

Comment: I had the same error and fixed it on .env, changing the serverVersion from mariadb-10.11.4 to 8.3